# Automophism of G and Haar measure

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group (written additively), $\lambda$ an automophism of $G$, and $\alpha$ a Haar measure in $G$. As the Haar measure is unique up to factor constant, $\lambda$ transform $\alpha$ into $c\alpha$ ($c\in\mathbb R_{>0}$).

My question is:

What does "$\lambda$ transform $\alpha$ into $c\alpha$"?

Thank you all.

Comment: The new measure $\mu(A) = \alpha(\lambda(A))$ on $G$ is also a Haar measure, so there's a positive number $c$ such that $\mu = c\alpha$. That is, for all measurable subsets $A$ in $G$, $\alpha(\lambda(A)) = c\alpha(A)$. That's the sense in which $\lambda$ turns $\alpha$ into $c\alpha$. For example, if $G = \mathbf R$, $\alpha = dx$, and $\lambda(x) = 2x$ then $\lambda$ transforms $\alpha$ into $2\alpha$. For generally, if $\lambda_t(x) = tx$ for a nonzero real number $t$, then $\lambda_t$ transforms $\alpha$ into $|t|\alpha$.

Comment: @KCd you should make this an answer. It's a perfect response I think.

Comment: If $A$ is measurable then $\lambda(A)$ is measurable? :\

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question, as noted user126033, is no. Indeed, by using the technique of Hamel basis, there is a Lebesgue non-measurable  automorhizms $\lambda : R \to R$. So we can not define $\mu$ by the formula $\mu(A)=\alpha(\lambda(A))$, because for some Lebesgue measurable set $A_0$ its image $\lambda(A_0)$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

In the case, when $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measurable, the answer to this question, as noted Cameron Williams, is yes.

P.S. I wanted to do a comment, but I had no  50 reputation.